# Apply Transform Curve to Mesh Geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm running into several issues with bezier curves in Geometry Nodes.
i have a node setup using a curve to distribute shingles along several pre-designated paths, they use the Euler of the curve to alling them correctly along the curve, so i need this curve

[image: NodeSetup]

the final idea of this project is to either make this applied geometry and bake these details down to create some gameready assets.

but it seems that baking these shingles down to a lowpoly mesh just crashes blender

and applying the modifier forces me to convert the curve into a mesh, completely making this node setup useless and destroying the rotation around the curve.

[image]

any way to get a curved roof using geometry nodes?

or a way to fix  the crash when trying to bake down these details?

[image]

Comment: don't know about the baking but you could have the node setup on a second object, let's say a plane, and import the curve there with an 'Object Info' node... also you can use right click > convert to > mesh and it works like applying all modifiers, even on a curve... and finally, you need a 'Realize Instances' node at the end of your setup to see any mesh as an output -that may help with baking too-

Answer (score 0):

- I think you need a 'Realize Instances' node at the end of your setup to have
  a mesh output
- also found in other thread you should place an attribute node pointing to your uv map in material

[image: some nodes you need]

to keep it clean you could have the node setup on a
second object, let's say a plane, and import the curve there with an
'Object Info' node... btw, just tried baking and worked fine with those changes

Answer (score 0):

when you finish adjustment ,just convert curve to mesh then[image]